# angular2 error with pipe filter in component

Tags: angular, filter, pipe, angular-pipe

I'm trying to add simple search filter in input, so it could filter my records in table.

But I'm receiving this kind of error:

```
app/components/orders/orders.component.ts(12,2): error TS2345:
 Argument of type '{ moduleId: string; selector: string; templateUrl:
 string; pipes: typeof FilterPipe[]; }' is not assignable to parameter
 of type 'Component'.   Object literal may only specify known
 properties, and 'pipes' does not exist in type 'Component'.
```

All files:

> orders.component.html, orders.component.ts, filter.pipe.ts
>   are in the same folder

And there is code in files:

**HTML in orders.component.html**

```
<input class="prompt" type="text" placeholder="Szukaj zlecenia..." [(ngModel)]="term">

<tr *ngFor="let order of orders">
    <td>{{order.orderNum}}</td>
    <td>{{order.clientNum}}</td>
    <td>{{order.dateCreated}}</td>
    <td>{{order.account}}</td>
    <td>{{order.status}}</td>
</tr>
```

---

**filter.pipe.ts**

```
 import { Injectable, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

    @Pipe({
        name: 'ordersFilter',
        pure: false
    })
    @Injectable()
    export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
        transform(items: any[], args: any[]): any {
            return items.filter(item => item.title.indexOf(args[0].title) !== -1);
        }
  }
```

---

**orders.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { OrderService } from '../../services/order.service'
    import { Order } from '../../structure/Order';
    import { Injectable, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
    import { FilterPipe } from './filter.pipe';

    @Component({
        moduleId: module.id,
        selector: 'orders',
        templateUrl: 'orders.component.html',
        pipes: [FilterPipe]
    })
```

It looks like it doesn't like `pipes: [FilterPipe]` but, as far as I know it is set properly.

In web browser I'm receiving this error:

```
zone.js:388 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: The
 pipe 'ordersFilter' could not be found ("      </thead>        <tbody>         <tr
 [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let order of orders | ordersFilter:term">
            <td>{{order.orderNum}}</td>             <td>{{order.clien"):
 OrdersComponent@28:6 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:
 Error: Template parse errors:(…) Error: Template parse errors: The
 pipe 'ordersFilter' could not be found ("      </thead>        <tbody>         <tr
 [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let order of orders | ordersFilter:term">
            <td>{{order.orderNum}}</td>             <td>{{order.clien"):
 OrdersComponent@28:6
```

Comment: are you using angular-cli ? latest version ?  if not please tell me the angular2 version

Comment: I'm using newest angular2 version from https://github.com/angular/angular
can't find exactly right version number in my repo

And i have created my project from scratch. I have angular-cli but haven't used it for that project.

Comment: see my answer @Krzysztof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably, you are using `ngModule` approach for your app if so than you are importing your pipe in incorrect way, you have to import your pipe in the module instead of your component i.e. orders component in your use case.

Try importing your pipe in higher module like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [FilterPipe,.... ],
  imports: [.... ],
  providers: [....],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

P.S:- Moreover, you can also create your pipe as module to import this in more than one modules.

Comment: Many thanks! This resolved problem with first error, 
but still something is wrong

Answer (score 2):

Hint: There is no need to add `@Injectable()` when there is already `@Pipe()`, `@Component()`, or `@Directive()`

Ensure you have `FilterPipe` added to `declarations: [FilterPipe]` of your current module

or

added the module that has

```
declarations: [FilterPipe],
exports: [FilterPipe]
```

to `imports: [...]` of your current module.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using angular 4, then you do not need to specify pipes in you @Component.