# Ionic 3 project is not generating production apk by throwing error

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular6

When I type `ionic cordova build android --prod` it throws this error:
Can't determine module for FilterPipe class in src./components/search/filter.pipe.ts. Add a filter pipe to module to fix it:

Here is the components module:

```
import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ImagesComponent } from './images/images';
import { SearchComponent } from './search/search';
import { FilterPipe } from '../pipes/filter.pipe';
import { SocketIoModule, SocketIoConfig } from 'socket.io-client';
const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http://localhost:3001', options: {} };

@NgModule({
  declarations: [PostsComponent, UserFriendsComponent,
    ImagesComponent, SearchComponent,
    FilterPipe,
    PeopleListComponent],
  imports: [IonicModule,
  ],
  exports: [ImagesComponent, SearchComponent,
    PeopleListComponent]
})
export class ComponentsModule { }
```

Instead of adding inside app.module I added it inside components module. But the problem is that if I even move it to app.module the same issue is happening. Here is also code for filter pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'filter',
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], value: string, prop: string): any[] {
        if (!items) return [];
        if (!value) return items;

        return items.filter(singleItem =>
            singleItem[prop].toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
        );

    }
}
```

How to fix this problem and generate production apk for testing successfully?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40958984/9247032

Comment: @AliMhanna it doesn't solve the problem.